# Centrar un elemento table CSS

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

**Deseo centrar una tabla mediante CSS en una página HTML.** No el contenido de los campos (filas-columnas) de la tabla, sino la tabla. El elemento tabla.

**Código:**

```
<div id="mostrar_tabla">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos" id="tabla_datos" method="POST">
       <table class="table table-striped" id="tabla" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
             ...........
       </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Código CSS intentado:

```
#tabla{
     display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Los elementos de tipo bloque (como el `div`), por defecto, van a obtener el 100% de la anchura disponible, por lo que en este caso tu `div` contenedor va a ocupar el 100% de la pantalla.

Para centrar la tabla dentro de dicho div, no tendrías que centrarte tanto en el contenedor, si no en el contenido, es decir, en la tabla.

Utilizando `margin: auto` sobre la tabla tendrías tu tabla centrada dentro de la página.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
#tabla{
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mostrar_tabla">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos" id="tabla_datos" method="POST">
       <table class="table table-striped" id="tabla" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
       <tr>
          <td>Celda</td>
          <td>Celda</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien lo podes centrar con: `margin: 0 auto;`

**nota:** lo cambien el ancho para que se pueda apreciar el centrado

```css
#tabla {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mostrar_tabla">
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos" id="tabla_datos" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tabla" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
      <tr>
        <td>Celda</td>
        <td>Celda</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Centrarlo Horizontalmente:
width: 600;

```css
#Table{
   margin: auto;
}
```

Centrarlo horizontal y verticalmente:
width: 600;
height: 600;

```css
#Table{
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -300px;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -300px;
}
```